# Footings Under Existing Concrete Slab Patio

Tags: concrete, patio, footings, pergola

I have an existing, unreinforced concrete slab patio in my back yard. It is 15'x22' in dimensions and the long edge runs parallel to the back of the house, separated from it by about 3'. I'm looking to add a pavilion cover and am unsure how to tackle footings.

There will be 6 posts spaced about 10 ft apart as shown in the attached image. Basically two rows of three, spaced at 10 ft, biased to the side of the patio away from the house. Currently they are about four inches from their respective edges/corners, with the obvious exception of the middle top post. I imagine it will be the most difficult to put a footing under. What's the best way to get footings under these so I have proper support for the pavilion?

Edit: existing slab is 4 inches thick, no rebar or mesh. Pavilion will be substantial, 8x8 posts and heavy timbers for beams and rafters of shed roof.

[image]

Comment: Rent a cement saw, make neat holes, dig down.

Comment: Why don't you move the 5 posts on the periphery off the slab and onto the ground?  That would make digging the hole for, and pouring the footer for the post easier.  Then you only have the one post in the middle of the slab to deal with.  I think you could manage that one post with a carbide tipped drill bit, a hammer drill, and some patience.

Comment: Instead of the 3 posts nearest the house, have you considered a properly attached ledger board to the house?

Comment: @crip659, I suspect that will ultimately be what I have to do. I'm just not experienced at it and didn't know if I was missing an easier/better way.

Comment: @SteveSh, I've thought of both moving the posts off the patio and attaching a ledger to the house. I don't care of the aesthetics of either option and windows, doors and roof line complicate attaching a ledger further.

Comment: There are many different stile concrete anchor for posts.

Comment: Thickness of the slab can be important for an answer.  It might be if the slab is thick enough, that footings you imagine won't be necessary.  More detail on the pavilion cover will help also.  Edit both into your question.

Comment: If using a metal post-to-concrete anchor designed to be attached to an already poured slab, be sure to use a _very_ sturdy one. Most of the ones I've seen readily available at my local big-box stores are _far_ to flimsy to trust to support anything overhead.

Comment: Where is this? In my region footings must be 24in diameter, "on hard", and at least below the frost line. A pad does not suffice. Roof support calculations include snow load. So you'd either pour concrete posts outside the pad, or cut into the pad.

Comment: @P2000, sure is northern Utah, likewise I believe fittings need to be fairly deep.